# response not updating when doing mutation after page reload but originally being updated which i can see in network tab

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, react-router, react-apollo

Here, i am trying to add "view" on mutation. the first view created after a reload runs into this issue. If you get the 404 page and hit the back button, it seems to work right the second time.

Here’s what happens, big picture (it happens too fast to see without pausing with debugger):
1.send mutation
2.get result
3.setViewId is called, which updates the URL query string
4.page is rendered, hits a check for the view based on ID. If it’s not in the show’s list of views, redirect to /not-found (404 page).

The last one is where it gets weird. When debugging, the shows include the new view in the network tab …but finding the view by ID returns undefined because the response i am getting from the useQuery does not update the record after page reload. I have no idea why at this point.

creating viewId and setViewId

```
  const viewId = Number(searchParams.get('viewId')) || undefined;
  const setViewId = useCallback<(viewId: number, replace?: boolean) => void>(
    (id: number, replace = false) => {
      navigate(route(`?viewId=${id}`), { replace });
      setViewZoneId(undefined);
    },
    [navigate, route],
  );

  // If view id is not set, set it
  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewId == null) setViewId(show.defaultViewId, true);
  }, [setViewId, show.defaultViewId, viewId]);

  // If there's a view but view zone id isn't set, set it
  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewId == null || viewZoneId != null) return;
    const view = show.views.find(({ id }) => id === viewId);
    if (view == null) return;
    setViewZoneId(view.viewZones[0].id);
  }, [show.views, viewId, viewZoneId]);
  // end hooks

  if (viewId == null) return null;

  const view = show.views.find(({ id }) => id === viewId);
  if (view == null) return <Navigate to={route('/not-found')} replace />;

  if (viewZoneId == null) return null;
```

passing setViewId into Component

```
 <CreateViewWizard {...wizard.props} show={show} setViewId={setViewId} />
```

here doing mutation and setting viewId in CreateViewWizard

```
 <Button
    color="primary"
    disabled={(step === 0 && name.trim() === '') || step > 2}
    onClick={async () => {
    setStep((prevStep) => prevStep + 1);
     if (step < 2) return;

     close();
     assert(typeof layoutId === 'number', 'Layout not set');

     const { data } = await createView({ variables: { layoutId, name, showId: show.id } });
     if (data?.createView?.view != null) setViewId(data.createView.view.id);
       }}
      variant="contained"
     >
    {step === 2 ? 'Create' : 'Next'}
  </Button>
```

Comment: What are the values of `viewId` and `show.views` when attempting to find an element by matching `viewId`?

Comment: @DrewReese , "viewId" is number, supposing that adding new view with id 2 then viewId will be "2" and show.views is array of object  like for id 2 it contains these params :  {
    "__typename": "View",
    "canDestroy": {...},
    "id": 2,
    "layout": {...},
    "name": "we",
    "showId": 1,
    "thumbnailUri": null,
    "viewZones": []
}

Answer (score 0):

If `viewId` is a string type and `id` is a number type, well, these can *never* be strictly equal (*`===`*), e.g. `"5" === 5` is ***always*** false. Try a type-safe comparison, e.g. `"5" === String(5)`.

Example:

```js
console.log('5 === "5"', 5 === "5"); // false
console.log('String(5) === "5"', String(5) === "5"); // true
```

Your code:

```
const view = show.views.find(({ id }) => String(id) === viewId);
```

Keep in mind that `Array.prototype.find` also potentially returns `undefined` when it doesn't find a matching element. You probably should check for any truthy `view` return value, and redirect when `view` is falsey.

```
if (!view) {
  return <Navigate to={route('/not-found')} replace />;
}
```